# Reset SVG to original transform matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, matrix, svg

I'm trying to reset my SVG back to its original transform matrix attribute. I have a scale function which uses this matrix to zoom in and out of the SVG. However, I want to be able to reset the SVG back to the transform matrix it first had.

I first load the transform matrix attribute into an array, which I then use in my scale function.

How can I store the original values so they won't be touched by my scale function, and so I can use them to reset the SVG?

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL7an0og/)

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newMatrix;
    var transMatrix = $("#svgGroup").attr("transform").replace(/[^0-9.,]+/, "");
    transMatrix = transMatrix.split(",");
    var origMatrix = [1,0,0,1, parseFloat(transMatrix[4]), parseFloat(transMatrix[5])];

    $("#out").click(function() {
            zoom(0.8)
    });
    $("#in").click(function() {
            zoom(1.25);
    });

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        alert(origMatrix)
            $("#svgGroup").attr("transform", "matrix(" + origMatrix + ")");
    });

    function zoom(scale) {
            for (var i=0; i<origMatrix.length; i++) {
                    origMatrix[i] *= scale;
             }
            newMatrix = "matrix(" +  origMatrix.join(' ') + ")";
            $("#svgGroup").attr("transform", newMatrix);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **deep clone** the original array. In order to do it, use `.slice(0)`

```
var origMatrix = [1,0,0,1, parseFloat(transMatrix[4]), parseFloat(transMatrix[5])];
var initialValue = origMatrix.slice(0);
```

Now you can use it in your reset function.

```
$("#reset").click(function() {
          origMatrix = initialValue.slice(0);
          $("#svgGroup").attr("transform", "matrix(" + origMatrix + ")");
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL7an0og/4/)

Comment: Thank you! That does the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be making this much harder than it needs to be by not using the SVG DOM. Resetting is merely a matter of changing the scale back to 1.

Here's [some simplified code](https://jsfiddle.net/kL7an0og/5/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#out").click(function() {
                zoom(0.8)
        });
        $("#in").click(function() {
                zoom(1.25);
        });

        $("#reset").click(function() {
                scale = 1.0 / $("#svgGroup")[0].transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix.a;
                zoom(scale);
        });

        function zoom(scale) {
                var transform = $("#svgGroup")[0].transform.baseVal.getItem(0);
                transform.matrix.a *= scale;
                transform.matrix.d *= scale;
                transform.matrix.e *= scale;
                transform.matrix.f *= scale;
        }
});
```

Comment: This works too :) However, I also have a panning function which uses the matrix. JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kL7an0og/11/). I was following this [tutorial](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/book/export/html/437) for my zoom and panning functions.

Comment: @truly-daunting I think the tutorial makes things seem harder than they are by avoiding built in functions that would make the tasks easier to implement.

Comment: How would I adjust the code above to have it so the zooming occurs where the user clicks on the screen? As it is, it zooms in at the top left all the time.